# Setup 2 servers on one machine

Tags: filezilla

How can I create **two server processes** running simultaneously on one pc using filezilla ?

Comment: Please add more information. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make a duplicate of the first instance.
2. In the directory of the second instance, execute

   "FileZilla Server" /servicename <...>

   "FileZilla Server" /servicedisplayname <...>

   "FileZilla Server" /install

You may not mix any of the commands, must execute one after another. Enter a unique identifier for both servicename and servicedisplayname that's different from the first instance.

Alternatively, you can insert/update the following lines into FileZilla Server.xml and then run with /install:
Code:

```
<Item name="Service name" type="string">newname</Item>
<Item name="Service display name" type="string">newdisplayname</Item>
```

1. Check your second instance in the Services Control Panel. Make sure both instances have a different listening socket.

From https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16015

Comment: In the forum there is an important mention that is really important and it is to run the FileZilla Server (2) as Administrator.